# Would missing dependency cause servlet fails to initialize in Struts 1.x?

Tags: java, servlets, struts, struts-1

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/chain/config/ConfigParser

I deployed a Struts 1.x web application on Weblogic 9. Refer to this specific error line, it seem `commons-chain-x.x.jar` is missing from the build path. I tried with several different versions of `commons-chain.jar` (1.1 & 1.2) but not helpful. I googled about it for hours as well, can't find any solution. What's the actual issue here? Is the missing `.jar` actually caused the servlet to initialize properly?

`p.s.` I know...Struts is long outdated and no longer widely used, but for some reasons I have to. Any help over here would be appreciated.

Library:

[image]

Full error log:

```
Nov 9, 2018 4:00:25 PM org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet init
SEVERE: Unable to initialize Struts ActionServlet due to an unexpected exception or error thrown, so marking the servlet as unavailable.  Most likely, this is due to an incorrect or missing library dependency.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/chain/config/ConfigParser
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initChain(ActionServlet.java:1680)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:278)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:507)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1723)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1700)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1620)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2761)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:889)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:333)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:635)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:566)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:136)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:104)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:320)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:815)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1222)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:433)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67)
    at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:518)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
<Nov 9, 2018 4:00:25 PM SGT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "action" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "StrutsExample".
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org/apache/commons/chain/config/ConfigParser
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:402)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:278)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: "Struts 1.x" is not a helpful diagnostic; be precise without making us look at an image. IIRC S 1.3.9 is on Chains 1.1. The files in your `lib` directory are not what's important, rather what's actually being deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to this [article](http://oracleappstechnology.blogspot.com/2011/09/http101216servlet-action-failed-to.html), clear up WebLogic server cache would helps. So it did according to my issue here. I simply deleted `tmp` folder and the error now disappeared.

> Weblogic Cache exists in $MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/ccg/servers/AdminServer/tmp
>   I had named my domain ccg. You can replace that with your domain name in the above path.

p.s. Folders `tmp`,`cache` and `logs` under the path above are safe for deletion.